# Relacionar una tabla a otras 5

Tags: sql

el problema que tengo es que necesito que las tablas asientos contengan la foreign key de una de las 5 tablas del plan de cuentas

Primeramente un asiento es una operación que afecta a dos cuentas, por ello necesito que cada asiento modifique la cuenta a la que se aplica por medio de una foreign key

Tengo estas tablas para que guarde el asiento

```
Asiento  (id, debe, haber, descripcion, foreign key)

Asiento2 (id, debe, haber, descripcion, foreign key)
```

También tengo un plan de cuentas, con una jerarquía para las cuentas

```
tipo       (id, nombre, codigo, saldo)
grupo      (id, nombre, codigo, saldo, id_tipo)
cuenta     (id, nombre, codigo, saldo, id_grupo)
sub_cuenta (id, nombre, codigo, saldo, id_cuenta)
auxiliar   (id, nombre, codigo, saldo, id_sub_cuenta)
```

El problema que tengo es que no se como relacionar las tablas de tal manera que al introducir la foreign key en una de las tablas asientos corresponda a una de los id existentes de las otras 5 tablas

Comment: Porque tienes dos tablas asientos si ambas tienen los mismos campos (y deben guardar los mismos datos supongo)?

Comment: El diseño es muy cuestionable; no obstante, tendrías que agregar las 5 columnas a las tablas de asiento, ó un `id` y algo para identificar la tabla de cuentas.

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera Es porque en un form de html necesito que se introduzcan 2 asientos en un solo POST xd

Comment: @Sal Tengo 7 tablas, las 5ta y 6ta reciben las foreing key de las otras 5, pero
necesito saber como hacer que sea excluyente, es decir que si recibe
la FK de una tabla no requiera la de las demás tablas

Answer (score 0):

según lo que entiendo de tu pregunta, lo que tienes que hacer es crear un asiento y relacionarlo con las otras tablas, pudiendo filtrar por alguna etiqueta o tipo:

```
Asientos
(id, debe, haber, descripcion, etiqueta ) 

tipo       (id, nombre, codigo, saldo, asiento)
grupo      (id, nombre, codigo, saldo, asiento, id_tipo)
cuenta     (id, nombre, codigo, saldo, asiento, id_grupo)
sub_cuenta (id, nombre, codigo, saldo, asiento, id_cuenta)
auxiliar   (id, nombre, codigo, saldo, asiento, id_sub_cuenta)
```

donde asiento es tu llave foranea

Ahora si no puedes modificar esas tablas por alguna particularidad, puedes crear una tabla que las relaciones

```
asientos_relaciones( asiento, codigo_foraneo, etiqueta)
```

Comment: Asiento como llave foránea supondría que a una cuenta sólo le corresponde un asiento.

Comment: @Slinker009 tal como dice Sal, no requiere que a una cuenta le corresponda un asiento, requiere que a un asiento le corresponda alguna cuenta de los 5 tipos de cuentas